# Crossmounting Virtualbox and WIndows 10

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, virtualbox

I am trying to access my Windows computer files inside of my Virtualbox VM.

I have already added file paths to the Virtualbox Shared Folders as permanent Machine Folders with 'automount' active. I still can't view these files within the VM.

I have also attempted to download the VirtualBox Guest Additions, but it fails to load.

The system runs on redhat - not sure if that's part of the problem. First time ever starting up a VM on a windows so I'm a little lost.

Answer (score 0):

Must have had the wrong Guest Additions download. Used the download below and used the following steps:

http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.20/

Set files to machine on VM settings
IN VM GUI: Settings > Storage 
Right click Controller:IDE 
Click 'Add Optical Drive'
Choose Disk - add  VBoxGuestAdditions_5.1.20.iso 
Save